# Admob Sessions confusion

Tags: android, admob

I recently finished my first Android game. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.LCMGameStudios.MatchIt but now I have a problem. Is about AdMob. I integrated AdMob, I have like 4000 impressions but still 0 Sessions. What's the problem? [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwGb9.png)